# 3D Face Scan using Camera in Snapchat

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera, android-gpuimageview

In Snapchat we could tap on the face on the camera. And it would generate a 3D wireframe around our face. i am wondering how do they achieve that?

Any library that does that?

***P.S.: Please help vote up for attract answers*** *I have searched SO and none of similar questions were asked...*

Comment: Yeah I would love to know how they do it as well